# How to get array from tagIds=3&tagIds=8

Tags: php, kohana-3

In PHP if a URL looks like this:

```
?tagIds[]=3&tagIds[]=8
```

PHP engine automatically transforms this into `tagIds` array. However, if a URL is missing square brackets:

```
?tagIds=3&tagIds=8
```

Automatic transformation into an array doesn't happen. How can I achieve the same manually in native PHP and in Kohana framework?

**UPDATE:**
It seems that I've found the answer. Can you please take a look at it's potential pitfalls? See my answer below.

Comment: I don't think you can; without the ```[ ]``` each next variable with the same name is just going to replace the previous one.

Comment: I think automatically I can't, but maybe manually through getting URL and parsing it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I've found a solution [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#76792):

```
function proper_parse_str($str) {
  # result array
  $arr = array();

  # split on outer delimiter
  $pairs = explode('&', $str);

  # loop through each pair
  foreach ($pairs as $i) {
    # split into name and value
    list($name,$value) = explode('=', $i, 2);

    # if name already exists
    if( isset($arr[$name]) ) {
      # stick multiple values into an array
      if( is_array($arr[$name]) ) {
        $arr[$name][] = $value;
      }
      else {
        $arr[$name] = array($arr[$name], $value);
      }
    }
    # otherwise, simply stick it in a scalar
    else {
      $arr[$name] = $value;
    }
  }

  # return result array
  return $arr;
}

$query = proper_parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Comment: You have problem with variable name:
`array(1) {
  ["tagIds[]"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}`

Comment: @stdob--, I've just copypasted it without yet running it. Where is the problem?

Comment: You need `tagsIds` name but by this code result you have `tagIds[]`

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to understand the problem

Comment: Ok. If you pass your tested input query to this code, as result you get the array as above. The name of variable in result array must be `tagIds` but in result this named `tagIds[]`. This is the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = "tagIds[]=3&tagIds[][]=8&tagIds=33";

function ext_parse_str( $str ) {
    $vs = explode("&", $str);
    $output = array();
    foreach ($vs as $v) {
        parse_str($v, $o);
        if (is_array($o) && count($o)==1) {
            $key = key($o);
            $value = $o[$key];
            var_dump($value);
            if ($value) {
                if (!is_array($value)) {
                    $output[$key][] = $value;
                } else {
                    if (!isset($output[$key])) {
                        $output[$key] = $value;
                    } else {
                        $output[$key] = array_merge_recursive( $output[$key], $value );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$query = ext_parse_str($str);
var_dump($query);
```

Comment: thanks, why is query string so strange `"tagIds[]=3&tagIds[][]=8&tagIds=33"? My query strings won't have square brackets

Comment: Just tested the possible value of query string )